# different string lengths using strtok

Tags: c, malloc, strtok

```
void redact_words(const char *text_filename, const char *redact_words_filename){
    FILE *fp = fopen(text_filename,"r");
    FILE *f2p = fopen(redact_words_filename,"r");
    FILE *f3p = fopen("result.txt", "w"); ;
    char buffer1[1000];
    char buffer2[1000];
    char *word;
    char *redact;
    

    
    char **the_words;
    
    //if ((fgets(buffer1, 1000 ,fp) == NULL) || (fgets(buffer2,1000 ,f2p) == NULL))
    
    fgets(buffer1,1000,fp);
    fgets(buffer2,1000,f2p);
    
    rewind(fp);
    rewind(f2p);
    
    int word_count = 0; 
    while (!feof(f2p)){
        char c = fgetc(f2p);
        if (c == ' '){
            word_count += 1;
        }
    }
    word_count += 1;
    
    the_words = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
    redact = strtok(buffer2, ", ");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++){
        the_words[i] = malloc(100);
        the_words[i] = redact;
        redact = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    }
    
    char result[256] = "";
    word = strtok(buffer1, " ");
    while (word != NULL){
        for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++){
            if (strcasecmp(the_words[i],word) == 0){
                for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
                    strcat(result,"*");
                    
                }
                strcat(result, " ");
                break; 
            }
            else{
                if (i==(word_count-1)){
                    strcat(result, word);
                    strcat(result, " ");
                }  
            } 
        }
        word = strtok(NULL," "); 
    }
    
    fputs(result, f3p);
    
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(f2p);
    fclose(f3p);
    free(the_words);
}
```

So this is my C code to replace words from the file called text_filename with asterixs if the word exists in a file called redact_words_filename. However, I noticed during the comparison with the 2 strings

```
if (strcasecmp(the_words[i],word) == 0){
                for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
                    strcat(result,"*");

                }
```

that when I have the word quick for example in both text files, the_words[i] contains a string of length 6 while the one in word contains a string of length 5, both containing the value quick, and so it is not registering as the same string. Why is one of the strings longer than another?

(P.s I apologise for the bad code quality)

Edit 1: Ok so I found out it has to do with \n which is put in at the end of every line. Trying to find a way to solve this.

Edit 2: I managed to get rid of \n through a simple for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++){
        the_words[i] = malloc(100);
        the_words[i] = redact;
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(redact); j++){
            if (redact[j] == '\n'){
                redact[j] = '\0';
            }
        }
        redact = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    }
```

Comment: You need to add both(`text` & `redact`) files to the question so that we could reproduce the error.

Comment: When debugging this kind of problem, it can be helpful to print values with guards, for example: `printf("Value: >>>%s<<< (len=%d)\n", value, strlen(value));` so that you can detect unexpected whitespace.

Comment: fgets will include the newline character in the output, thats why you are getting one

Comment: Thank you for the help. I apologise for the unstructured and messy question. And sorry for not including the text files.

Comment: `while (!feof(f2p)){` approach for finding word count is amiss.  Consider a file of `"\n"` would report a word count of 1 and `" abc "` reports a word count of 3.

Comment: What do you think `the_words[i] = redact;` does? If you think it copies character-by-character from `redact` into `the_words[i]`, why do you think that `the_words[i] = malloc(100);` is different? Hint: assigning a pointer variable is just like assigning an integer; the new value (a pointer) replaces the old value (also a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    the_words = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
    redact = strtok(buffer2, ", ");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++){
        the_words[i] = malloc(100);
        the_words[i] = redact;
        redact = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    }
```

Two obvious problems just here

- you allocate space for 3 pointers in `the_words` but then you go and put `word_count` words into it.  So if word_count > 3, you'll overflow and get undefined behavior
- for each word, you allocate 100 bytes, and then throw away that allocation, instead storing a pointer into buffer2.  The buffer currently contains the word but that will change next time you read into it.  You should just use `the_words[i] = strdup(redact);` to both allocate the right amount of memory, and copy the string into the allocated memory.